# Stack in Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, stack

I need help with a code in Assembly.

I'm coworking on this and my group just did this Assembly code where it supposed to do the same as what I did in #c.

Could someone help me to understand what happens with de stack at least on the first steps so I can go on and conclude the rest?

I'm a begginer in Assembly, but I know that these lines just save the value for the calling function, takes a frame for the called function and save space for local variables, but I can't figure out the next first steps.

```
mov ebp
mov ebp,esp
sub esp, 16
```

Here is what I did in #c:

```
void mult_integer(int X[A_Linhas][A_Colunas], int number)
{
  int c, l;

  for (l = 0; l < A_Linhas; l++)
  {
    for (c = 0; c < A_Colunas; c++)
    {
      X[l][c] = number * X[l][c];
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the code in Assembly:

```
mul_integer:
        push    ebp 
        mov     ebp, esp 
        sub     esp, 16 
        mov     dword [ebp-4H], 0
        jmp     L_020

L_017:  mov     dword [ebp-8H], 0
        jmp     L_019

L_018:  mov     edx, dword [ebp-4H]
        mov     eax, edx
        add     eax, eax
        add     eax, edx
        shl     eax, 2
        mov     edx, eax
        mov     eax, dword [ebp+8H]
        lea     ecx, [edx+eax]
        mov     edx, dword [ebp-4H]
        mov     eax, edx
        add     eax, eax
        add     eax, edx
        shl     eax, 2
        mov     edx, eax
        mov     eax, dword [ebp+8H]
        add     edx, eax
        mov     eax, dword [ebp-8H]
        mov     eax, dword [edx+eax*4]
        imul    eax, dword [ebp+0CH]
        mov     edx, eax
        mov     eax, dword [ebp-8H]
        mov     dword [ecx+eax*4], edx
        add     dword [ebp-8H], 1
L_019:  cmp     dword [ebp-8H], 2
        jle     L_018
        add     dword [ebp-4H], 1
L_020:  cmp     dword [ebp-4H], 3
        jle     L_017
        nop
        leave
        ret
```

Comment: "but I can't figure out the next first steps" - it's unclear what exactly you are asking. PS: that's very inefficient asm code.

Comment: What's unclear? 

I want to know what happens to the stack in "mov     dword [ebp-4H], 0 " for example... It's not clear to me what does this manipulation of ebp-4H or ebp -8H means... I know it's somehow running the matrix, but still not clear. I just need to know the beggining so I can figure out the rest.

Comment: It isn't. `[ebp-4]` is `l` and `[ebp-8]` is `c` (or the other way around, can't be bothered to check). Clearly, that corresponds to `l = 0`.

Comment: Oh, got it! Thank! When I write "mov edx, [ebp-4]" or +4, or -4, +8, -8 what am I doing with the stack, exactly?

Comment: Assuming you have first copied the stack pointer into `ebp`, you are accessing various parts of it. Your locals are typically at negative offsets, arguments at positive.

Comment: What exactly is #c?

Comment: it's just c @fuz

Comment: stack is just ordinary memory, like any other, the only "special" thing about it, that stack is where the `esp` register points to, and several instruction use this memory area implicitly (`call, ret, push, pop, ...`). So you can run this piece in debugger, break on the first instruction of the function, and use the debugger to view memory content around `esp` address (after the `call function` instruction it will point at the return address value stored in stack by `call`), and watch out how `ebp` is set relatively to that, and how the other area of memory around is used for local variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When I write `mov edx, [ebp-4]` or +4, or -4, +8, -8 what am I doing with the stack, exactly?

Take a look at the stack (diagram from [Wikipedia's Call Stack article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Structure)).  Note that low memory addresses are at the top of this diagram, while higher memory address are at the bottom.

[image: stack layout with a frame pointer]

The *frame pointer* is stored in register `ebp` (on x86). It contains the address of the *Return Address*.

Your local variables are stored before the *Return Address*. Variable `c` is 4 bytes in size. By subtracting 4 from the `ebp` address, you are now pointing to your first local variable, `c`. Subtract another 4 (making it -8), and you're now pointing to your second local variable `l`.

Comment: Excellent! Just what I need to conclude. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Another one: if, instead of subtracting 4 I sum 4 or 8, what I am expecting to get? @Krii

Comment: @LéoEduardoSilva Instead of moving "up" the stack, you will move "down" it. If you look at the image, you can see that "below" the frame pointer are the function parameters. :)